# Conflicts of records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, composite-primary-key

I have a following problem. I have a `.tsv` file (for movies, years and genres). I want to upload it to SQL Server 2012.

I created a table

```
CREATE TABLE Genres2
(
MovieName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Year int NOT NULL,
Genre varchar(255) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (MovieName, Year)
);
```

While uploading it

```
BULK INSERT Genres3
FROM 'c:\Users\genres6.tsv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR='\t',
    ROWTERMINATOR='\n'
);
```

I get an error

> The duplicate key value is

But notepad++ says, that there is only one such value in the file.

Any ideas how to solve it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You defined `(MovieName, Year)` as primary key, are you sure you searched for this combination and not `MovieName` or `Year`? What should be unique?

Comment: it is best to have an INT column as your Primary key, Have you considered using an Identity Column for a Primary Key ??

Comment: just out of curiosity in your .tsv file do you have column names in your very 1st row ???

Comment: @MuhammedAli - "it is best to have an INT column as your Primary key" is not a valid assumption. you have many considerations for using `bigint` or `uniqueidentifier`

Comment: @Yosi why would you choose any of these two types you have mentioned ???

Comment: I don't have Column names in the very first row

Comment: I assigned int to the Year column. The could be duplicates with it, so I can not use it as Primary Key. Combination of MovieName and Year is unique

Comment: `uniqueidentifier` can be generated without having to go through the database to assure uniqueness (see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371762/what-exactly-is-guid-why-and-where-i-should-use-it) for more details), and `bigint` is more scalable (technically - you can produce more values.. )

Comment: @Yosi you do realise that GUID is a 16-byte and Bigint is 8 bytes in size, where as INT is only 4 byte. The bigger your Primary Key Column is in size less performance you get.

Comment: "bigint is more scalable" with INT you can add more then 2 billion records in a table and forget about billions if number of rows in your tables start getting into millions I think you should consider Partitioning NOT BIGINT :)

Comment: I'm not saying what to use here, I said this isn't a valid saying, that's all.

Comment: @Yosi I believe it is absolutely valid to say so, as whenever possible Have you primary key as INT will give you better performance compare to any other data type.]

Comment: What you believe isn't what everyone else does :) I can see your point about bigint (as said here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124631/sql-server-int-or-bigint-database-table-ids) but there it's totally reasonable to choose Guid over int in many cases, as said here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804910/sql-guid-vs-integer

Comment: @Yosi, @Muhammed Ali Having an autoincrement or unique column in your primary key will not give you any performance advantage if it is not used for joins or bears no meaning. Eg. having a clustered index just on `ID  int identity` column in a fact table makes it only worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple troubleshooting here:

1. Disable or drop primary key constrain and load data.
2. Run a query to find duplicate entries in proposed key column.
3. If there no duplicates, then add constrain to copy to a new table with such constrain.

Comment: (...just typing and you beat me to it.)

Comment: @whytheq It happened to me many times too. I also added a comment to fuel "discussion" )

Comment: Thanks for advice. It returned two values: 8minutes, 2011 and 8Minutes, 2011. The difference is that Capital Letter after 8.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879846/how-to-configure-mysql-to-be-case-sensitive. You can make whole DB case sensitive or just certain columns.

Comment: case insensitive is probably a lot easier - in terms of your sanity

Comment: Depends on requirements, but I do agree with you, @whytheq