# Is there a way to create an SQL SERVER table with unique rows?

Tags: sql-server, unique

I want my table to have unique rows, but not unique columns. Is that an option? I want to be able to have same values on multiple rows in the same column, but not a 100% copy of another row...

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761679/is-there-a-way-to-make-an-entire-mysql-row-unique) question but it is about MySQL, and I need it for SQL SERVER.

My specific table (conversation-staffer) is this:

```
conversation_id | staffer_id | handled
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Downvoter - What is wrong with the question?

Comment: I'm only guessing - but your question lacks information, table structure, data sample, desired output.

Comment: @sagi, Is it just me? Or are you guys talking in Hebrew?

Comment: @FelixPamittan - Yes. I told him that my question is general, and do not have to do with any specific table nor has to do with an output. I only asked for your help in a followup question in the comment, but you DID answer my question. I am not very good in English so I tried to explain that in our native language.

Comment: @FelixPamittan Yup, why?:)

Comment: @sagi - I guess it is forbidden, I didn't know. After reading my response, do you still think the question is bad?

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but I told you why they did. Yes it's not formatted well, you should have included table structure and DDL..

Comment: @sagi I edited my question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a unique index that includes all the columns of the table:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX <index name> ON <tablename>(<columns>);
```

Alternatively, you could set all columns as your Primary Key. But you have to drop the `PK` first if the table already has.

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> DROP CONSTRAINT <constraint_name>;    
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ADD PRIMARY KEY (<columns>);
```

Comment: That way I could have to different row with some of the columns similar?

Comment: If you put all the columns in the unique index or the PK, you can't have rows with same data on all columns. If some of the columns can have similar data, then you exclude them in the column list on your index.

Comment: If you add a `UNIQUE INDEX` containing *all* the columns then each unique *combination* of row values can only be stored once, but inside each individual column, or subsets of columns, you can have duplicates.

Comment: Could you please edit your code for the table "conversation-staffer" and the columns "conversation_id", "staffer_id", "handled"? I am not very strong in SQL :\

Comment: And please upvote the question. I do not understand why it was downvoted. If it is worth answering then it is worth questioning.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure how to insert them... I tried this: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IndexName ON [conversation-staffer](<conversation_id>,<staffer_id>,<handled>); `

Comment: Ho! I have succeeded. Thanks A LOT!