# MySQL Create Table with Multiple Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I would like to create a table that has multiple foreign keys to multiple different tables (as the relationship is many to many).

```
#creating t1
CREATE TABLE t1
(ID          INT               AUTO_INCREMENT          primary key,
x1           VARCHAR(50)
);

#Creating t2
CREATE TABLE t2
(v1       VARCHAR(50),
v2        VARCHAR(50),
primary key (v1, v2)
);

#creating attended table
CREATE TABLE t3
(ID        INT,
v1         VARCHAR(50),
v2         VARCHAR(50),
primary key (ID, v1, v2 ),
foreign key(v1)                 references t2(v1),
foreign key(v2)                 references t2(v2),
foreign key(ID)                 references t1(ID)
);
```

Above is my code. I get no errors for creating t1 and t2.  However, I get the following code when I try to create t3:

> ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreign key is the complete key of the other table - you can not only use half of it as FK.

`t2` has a combined primary key. when referencing a fk in t3 you need both.

See [Why use multiple columns as primary keys (composite primary key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626158/why-use-multiple-columns-as-primary-keys-composite-primary-key)

To create a complex FK see [SQL Server: adding foreign key on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41305693/sql-server-adding-foreign-key-on-multiple-columns)
or for MySql see [Multiple-column foreign key in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953035/multiple-column-foreign-key-in-mysql)

Comment: Okay.  So I would have to code this then?

    foreign key(v1, v2)                 references t2(v1, v2)

Comment: Mark as answer or delete questions - I merily did your research for you,answers were already on SO.