# Primary Key on Local TClientDataSet using Briefcase Model

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, datasnap, tclientdataset

When a DataSnap Client app connects to a DataSnap Server's Remote Data Module and uses a `TDataSetProvider` + `TClientDataSet`, it caches a db table (or view) local to the client app.  The user can make changes to the data in the TClientDataSet locally and `ApplyUpdates(0)` to synchronize the changes with the server.  This all makes sense.

Using a SQL Server 2008 db, the primary key can be either an `identity` or a `GUID` field.  Assuming the user will be *offline* while they add new records to the local `TClientDataSet`, how does the local `TDataSetProvider` and `TClientDataSet` handle assignment of the primary key field when the user creates a **new** record?  Since the locally created records may be part of a master/detail relationship, it seems logical that a new primary key would **need** to be created locally.  How is that resolved when the user does an `ApplyUpdates(0)'?

When several users create records in **offline** mode, how are primary key collisions resolved when they each do an `ApplyUpdates(0)`?

Is an `identity` field better than a `GUID` field, or visa versa? Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you like your primary keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404040/how-do-you-like-your-primary-keys)

Comment: That article is a general discussion of what kind of primary key is best.  My question is specifically whether `TDataSetProvider` and `TClientDataSet` create offline primary keys in cached datasets and how primary keys are handled by these components when users synchronize their local cache with the server via a call to `ApplyUpdates(0)`.  There may be issues with the way the components handle the primary key when using an `identity` or `GUID` field -- thus question about which is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be the closest answer:

[How to use AutoInc fields with DataSnap](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20847)

Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: A `uniqueidentifier` will do the trick for our needs, including handling most master/client detail relationships in the locally cached data. The only exception that we'll need to handle is primary key violations when two users working in offline mode create new records that have the same GUID. I know GUIDs are **always** unique. However, they are not guaranteed to be unique when an ethernet / token ring address is not available at the time that the GUID is created. In this case, there can be an overlap between GUIDs created on different computers.